# Custom NSPopUpButtonCell drawImage:withFrame:inView not getting called

Tags: cocoa, appkit

I have a custom NSPopUpButtonCell and I'm trying to override drawImage:withFrame:inView. Strangely, the drawImage method is never called, but the image appears on screen. What am I missing?

I've checked to make sure my cell is properly installed -- I am getting drawWithFrame:inView:controlView messages.

Note that I'm trying to compensate for an image only gradient-style button not properly centering it's image (it's 1 pixel to the left of where it should be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSPopupButtonCell inherits from [NSMenuCell](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItemCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSMenuItemCell) and NSMenuCell has a method called [drawImageWithFrame:inView:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenuItemCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMenuItemCell/drawImageWithFrame:inView:) which might be what you're looking for. It has several other drawing methods too so check those and see which one is being called.